# Brute Force Algorithm Issue

Tags: java, algorithm

I've look over the code several time but I keep getting a Array Out of Bound at the line that states:

**sum = sum + vectorArray[z]; }**

Can anyone see what's wrong?

```
public class HW1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // The numbers for n are not relevant
    System.out.println("Please enter a number for the length of n.");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    // Creates an array with n values
    int[] vectorArray = new int[n];

    // Inputs random numbers into the array ranging from -100 to 100.
    int dummy;
    int temp = 0;

    // Loop to generate negative and positive numbers into the array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        dummy = (int)(Math.random()*2);
        if (dummy == 0) { 
            temp = -1; 
        } else {
            temp = 1; } 

        vectorArray[i] = ((int)(Math.random()*101)) * temp;
        System.out.println(vectorArray[i]); }

    int max = -1;
    int sum;

    for (int x = 0; x < vectorArray.length; x++) {
        for (int y = x; x < vectorArray.length; y++) {
        sum = 0;
            for (int z = x; z <= y; z++) {
                sum = sum + vectorArray[z]; }
                max = Math.max(max, sum);
        } } 
    System.out.println("The max: " +  max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `<=`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to help future visitors since it is about a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change x to y   in the for loop

```
  for (int y = x; y < vectorArray.length; y++) {

                  ^
 sum = 0;
            for (int z = x; z <= y; z++) {
                sum = sum + vectorArray[z]; }
```